# Stop web view Zooming

Tags: android, webview

I have create a web view & i need to make web view not able to zoom. what i have done so far is:

```
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webFreeFlow.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_DEFAULT);
webFreeFlow.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
webFreeFlow.requestFocus();
```

this hide the web view zoom controls. But web view is zoomed on double tap.

How can i get this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to disable zoom.

```
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code

```
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

by

```
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

and also use this code `webFreeFlow.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);`

If still not solve, then use this code

```
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```